# Skrollr Mobile, Overflow Hidden;

Tags: html, css, skrollr

I have read the documentation over at skrollr. My site is wrapped in the

```
<div id="skrollr-body">
..site here...
</div>
```

And all my fixed elements are located below that, outside of those tags.

In my regular desktop view it works fine, but when I test it on a mobile, I can see that skrollr adds overflow:hidden; to both the body tag, and also the html tag.

if I add

```
html {
overflow:scroll !important;
}
```

I can scroll on the mobile, but all the skrollr functions break.

Why are these css rules being added to my elements, and what do I have to do (other than what I've already done) to get the page to scroll on mobile and still have the skrollr functions intact.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
body {
  height: 100% !important
}
```

or

```
#skrollr-body {
  min-height: 100%
}
```

Also, try to take out of #skrollr-body any fixed element like a bootstrap navigation bar.

Comment: Not working. 1st option changes the behaviour, 2nd has no effect.